SwiftUI View with optional bound parameter
I am trying to modify Stewart Lynch's Rating View to support box a static representation and a "control" to set the rating. To do that, I need some optional properties to address the two different conditions. So
currentRating is the current rating, to create a view of that number of symbols.
maxRating is the maximum possible rating &
mutableRating is the bound current rating, so I can display the cornet value as filled symbols, with the remainder of symbols up to maxRating unfilled, as well as an unfilled and struck through symbol to set the rating to 0.
Where I am having problems is making that bound parameter also optional. I found this that suggests it should be possible, but that is also rather old. In any case, I have tried various permutations as seen in the commented lines, trying to get Initialization to work, with various different failures.
struct RatingView: View {
    var currentRating: Int?
    
    var maxRating: Int?
    @Binding var mutableRating: Int?
    
    var width:Int
    var color: UIColor
    var sfSymbol: String
    
    public init(
        currentRating: Int? = nil,
        maxRating: Int? = nil,
        mutableRating: Binding<Int?>,
//        mutableRating: Binding<Int>?,
//        mutableRating: (Binding<Int>)?,
        width: Int = 20,
        color: UIColor = .systemYellow,
        sfSymbol: String = "star"
    ) {
        self.currentRating = currentRating
        self.maxRating = maxRating
        self._mutableRating = mutableRating
//        self._mutableRating = mutableRating ?? Binding.constant(nil)
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.sfSymbol = sfSymbol
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Text("")
    }
}

#Preview ("mutating") {
    struct PreviewWrapper: View {
        @State var rating: Int? = 3
        
        var body: some View {
            RatingView(
                maxRating: 5,
                mutableRating: $rating,
                width: 30,
                color: .red,
                sfSymbol: "heart"
            )
        }
    }
    return PreviewWrapper()
}

#Preview ("non mutating") {
    struct PreviewWrapper: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            RatingView(
                currentRating: 3,
                width: 20,
                color: .red,
                sfSymbol: "heart"
            )
        }
    }
    return PreviewWrapper()
}

So, my first question is, can I still do this in iOS 17 and if so how?
And second, I am curious about the details in what is the difference between these three approaches to Init arguments?
mutableRating: Binding<Int?>
mutableRating: Binding<Int>?
mutableRating: (Binding<Int>)?

EDIT: Clarification of failures
When I use
mutableRating: Binding<Int?>
&
self._mutableRating = mutableRating
I get Missing argument for parameter 'mutableRating' in call in the non mutating preview. Which I assume means that the parameter is not actually optional, which makes sense given the differences mentioned.
If I change the argument line to
mutableRating: Binding<Int>? to make the parameter itself optional then I get Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<Int>' to type 'Binding<Int?>' on the initialization line. One of the fix options offered suggests that this might work, self._mutableRating = mutableRating ?? nilbut that producesCannot assign value of type 'Binding?' to type 'Binding<Int?>'` which brings us back around to the change in the argument.

The first is a binding to an optional type, the second one is an optional binding to a type and the third is the same as the second. So if you use them as parameters to a function then you can pass nil to the two last but the first one can not be nil although its bound value can be nil.

@joakim-danielson I had a sense that 3 was just a more verbose version of 2. So what are the use cases for those first two? And how do I initialize the second one?

From my perspective, I believe you're looking for:
public init(
    ...
    mutableRating: Binding<Int?> = .constant(nil),
    ...
) { }

With the code above, both mutating and non mutating previews are valid.

Binding<Int?>: a binding struct that holds a Optional<Int> as its wrappedValue.
Binding<Int>?: an Optional<Binding<Int>>
(Binding<Int>)? equal to Binding<Int>?


Aha! I will need to do some reading to understand what that .constant(nil) is doing exactly, but I think that is going to do the job. Now I can get all of this working and then post separately to see if someone says "That's got all sorts of code smells, even if it does work" :)

Actually, this is the right to do with @Binding, especially when you mock up data within preview mode. You should take a look at SwiftUI tutorials.

I think .optional is only meant to be used with previews.

I previously used it as a placeholder UI. I had a view with 2 states, the first state is for showcase only, which uses .constant to represent a kind of demo data. Other state for real data that was fetched from BE.

Here is my simplified solution to using an optional binding to an optional type and an optional property together.
struct TestView: View {
    var mutableRating: Binding<Int?>?
    let currentRating: Int?

    init(mutableRating: Binding<Int?>?) {
        self.mutableRating = mutableRating
        currentRating = nil
    }

    init(rating: Int?) {
        self.mutableRating = Optional<Binding<Int?>>.none
        currentRating = rating
    }

    var body: some View {
        if let mutableRating {
            TextField("Rating", value: mutableRating, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)))
                .padding()
        } else if let currentRating {
            Text(currentRating.formatted())
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    return TestView(mutableRating: .constant(42))
}

#Preview ("non mutating") {
    struct PreviewWrapper: View {

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TestView(rating: 3)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    return PreviewWrapper()
}


Tested on iOS 17.4 and macOS 14

But does it work without a mutableRating being passed? That seems to be where I am hitting the wall. I can get it to work when I DO pass that argument, but in the Non Mutating variant I get an error that makes it seem like the parameter isn't actually optional like I need it to be.

I don't think I understand your second preview example, why do you want to pass a constant value to a binding property?

That's the thing, I don't. So I need one parameter used in the first preview that takes the binding, and then a different parameter in the second preview that takes a simple int. And both have to be optional as a result.

Ok, I missed that you used a different property for the constant value
